# How to get Page Layout from item in SharePoint Online

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-online

I have tried to figure out how to get the Page Layout used for a specific page, but to no vail.

The code I am using is:

```
 public void ItemAddedHandler(ClientContext clientContext, Guid listId, int listItemId) {

    var web = clientContext.Web;

    List list = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetById(listId);
    ListItem item = list.GetItemById(listItemId);
    clientContext.Load(item, i => i["PublishingPageLayout"]);

    // item["PublishingPageLayout"] should contain the Page Layout used but is empty.
}
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: I have made a test and is checking the "PublishingPageLayout" property on delete also, and then I can get the Page Layout for the file. Strange. It seems that the Layout is not set completely on Item Added (I am using an event receiver to trigger the code in creation of the file)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you call `ExecuteQuery` / `ExecuteQueryAsync` on the `clientContext` object before trying to access item properties.

When working with Client Object Model, everything you do before executing either of these methods is actually building the query of *what to retrieve*, but until you execute the query itself, nothing will be sent/received to/from SharePoint.

Comment: The actual error was not that I had forgotten the ExecuteQuery because I got nothing even after adding the ExecuteQuery. The property for the PublishingPageLayout did not apply until the ItemUpdatedHandler was executed. So when the document was actually added, the property does not exists, but on a second update my eventreceivers on UpdateItem was updated with the pagelayout.

Answer (score 0):

The correct code is below. I had to  check for the pagelayout property in the updateitem eventhandler, and not in the itemadded handler.

```
public void ItemUpdatedHandler(ClientContext clientContext, Guid listId, int listItemId, ContextInfo logContext) {
    ListItem item = list.GetItemById(listItemId);
    clientContext.Load(item, i => i["PublishingPageLayout"], i => i.DisplayName);
    clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
    FieldUrlValue fuv = (FieldUrlValue)item["PublishingPageLayout"];
}
```